# Send by post with restangular

Tags: angularjs, json, rest, restangular

I'm trying to send by post a json with restangular but this don't return me anything.

Code:

```
$scope.userPost = {

        title: 'foo',
        body: 'bar',
        userId: 1
    }

    $scope.registerUser=function(){
        $scope.people = Restangular.all('post').post($scope.userPost);
        console.log($scope.people);
    }
```

It return me this:

```
{ "restangularCollection": false, "$object": {} }
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/post 404 (Not Found)
```

Usually I use this with ajax and it return me a json:

```
$.ajax('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    title: 'foo',
    body: 'bar',
    userId: 1
  }
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/post` !== `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` also it return a promise, so you need to get response by using `Restangular.all('post').post($scope.userPost).then(function(data) { console.log(data); });`

Answer (score 0):

Restangular works with promises, so, you should be doing something like:

```
$scope.registerUser = function () {
    Restangular.all('post').post($scope.userPost).then((data) => {
        $scope.people = data;
        console.log($scope.people);
    });
}
```

Or you can take advantage of its [enhanced promises](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#enhanced-promises) and do something like:

```
$scope.registerUser = function () {
    $scope.people = Restangular.all('post').post($scope.userPost).$object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 4+

```
constructor(private restangular: Restangular){}

// latter in your method
const baseUsers = this.restangular.all('post');
baseUsers.post({'title':'foo','body': 'bar','userId': '1'})
.subscribe(data => { console.log(data); });
```